# Overwrite Azure resource values with Azure policy values

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-policy

Is it possible to overwrite Azure resource values with Azure policy values? I am trying to fix the VM size/sku. I created the below Policy with an `append` effect which fails VM creation as it cannot overwrite the default/given VM size/sku.

```
{
    "if": {
        "field": "type",
        "equals": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
    },
    "then": {
        "effect": "append",
        "details": [{
                "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/sku.name",
                "value": "Standard_D4_v3"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to ***overwrite*** a resource value using an ARM policy `append` effect.  The behavior you are experiencing is by design as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/effects#append).

Since a VM's SKU is a single value vs. a collection/array of values, the only action you could hope to take is to overwrite the original value.  But, as you are seeing, an ARM policy will revert to the `deny` effect instead in this case.

Comment: so is there any other way to silently enforce a default value? I mean not just deny a request but actually replace the entered value with a default value?

Comment: Not with policies.  You could author an ARM or Terraform template for your users to use that only allows a certain set of SKU's to be selected.